# Building string with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have the following Problem:

I'm trying to build a simple string like that:

```
for(var x in classicde) {
    specificWines += "<li><a onClick='displayWine(" + "'GV'" + ")'>" + classicde[x] + "</a></li>";
}
```

Then I insert this string in the DOM structure with:

```
var list = document.getElementById("leftmenu-list");
list.innerHTML = specificWines;
```

The result is the following(something like that i have shortened it):

```
<ul id="leftmenu-list">
    <li><a onclick="displayWine(" gv')'>Classic1</a></li>
</ul>
```

So there is a problem within the onclick event and i am not able to find the issue.

Comment: Why do you need any concatenation between your `onClick`'s parenthesis and "gv"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong around `'displayWine(" + "'GV'" + ")'` it should be `'displayWine(" + "\"GV\"" + ")'` so the single quotes contains double quotes and do not break the attribute on render. `\` is used to escape the quote so it doesn't break the JS code.

```
for(var x in classicde) {
    specificWines += "<li><a onClick='displayWine(" + "\"GV\"" + ")'>" + classicde[x] + "</a></li>";
}
```

Otherwise as you see you end up with the single quote breaking the attribute. If you pass a string inside a string you need to make sure you use different quotes.

This should now render as

```
<li><a onclick='displayWine("gv")'>Classic1</a></li>
```